# Janusgraph troubles to understand how to manipulate data from gremlin query

Tags: javascript, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm trying to reconstruct the data retrieved with a gremlin query from a graph.
Precisely I'm having troubles finding an efficient way to manipulate the data that comes back.

The version of JanusGraph I'm using it's the 0.3.1 and it's running on Cassandra + ES, also it is configured with the ConfiguredGraphFactory. So I can create graphs dynamically.

I'm using gremlin javascript version 3.4.2 (the 3.3.3 doesn't work properly)

I built a little example to better explain what I mean.
The graph in this examples is created without a schema.

First of all, I'll connect to the graph using this functions:

```js
const gremlin = require('gremlin');

const { Graph } = gremlin.structure;
const { DriverRemoteConnection } = gremlin.driver;

const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const P = gremlin.process.P;

const GREMLIN_URL = "ws://localhost:8182/gremlin";
const GRAPH_NAME = "graphtest";

let connection;

function getTraversal() {
    const graph = new Graph();
    connection = new DriverRemoteConnection(GREMLIN_URL, { traversalSource: GRAPH_NAME });
    return g = graph.traversal().withRemote(connection);
}

function closeConnection() {
    if(connection && connection.close) connection.close();
}
```

Then I'll create some Vertices and Edges.

We'll have one User, two Institution and two 'trained' edges connecting the user to the institutions:

```js
async function createVerticesAndEdges() {
    const g = getTraversal();
    const userV = await g.addV('user').property('name', 'Emily').property('identityId', '1234').next();
    console.log('user', userV);
    const institutionV = await g.addV('institution').property('name', 'University of California').property('identityId', 'CA83').next();
    console.log('institution', institutionV);
    const institutionV2 = await g.addV('institution').property('name', 'University of Illinois').property('identityId', 'IL847').next();
    console.log('institution2', institutionV2);
    const trainedE = await g.addE('trained').property('title', 'MS in Computer Science').property('grade', 'B')
        .from_(__.V().has('identityId', '1234')).to(__.V().has('identityId', 'CA83')).next();
    console.log('trained', trainedE);
    const trainedE2 = await g.addE('trained').property('title', 'Political Science').property('grade', 'A')
        .from_(__.V().has('identityId', '1234')).to(__.V().has('identityId', 'IL847')).next();
    console.log('trained2', trainedE2);
    closeConnection();
}
```

Then, let's say I want to retrieve all the trainings that a user took, and I'd also like to have the name of the institution where the training was taken.

So the query I run is this:

```js
async function getUserTrainings() {
    const g = getTraversal();
    const result = await g.V()
        .hasLabel('user')
        .has('identityId', '1234')
        .as('u').outE()
        .hasLabel('trained')
        .inV()
        .path()
        .unfold()
        .where(P.neq('u'))
        .toList();
    closeConnection();
    console.log(result);
}
```

and I get this output:

```
[ 
    Edge {
    id: { relationId: 'odxqw-3b4-27th-38o'
        },                                                                                                                                                                                     alber@DESKTOP-8CVHP91 MINGW64 ~/Ref    label: 'trained',
    outV: 4288,
    inV: 4200,
    properties: {}
    },
  Vertex { id: 4200, label: 'institution', properties: undefined
    },
  Edge {
    id: { relationId: 'odxco-3b4-27th-3ao'
        },
    label: 'trained',
    outV: 4288,
    inV: 4272,
    properties: {}
    },
  Vertex { id: 4272, label: 'institution', properties: undefined
    }
]
```

This is not bat, I could use the vertices ids and the edges inV to reconstruct the relations and return the data as I wanted it, but the problem is, as you can see, that this query doesn't return the properties. So it's kinda useless.

But then, looking through the gremlin docs I found the valueMap() step, so I can slightly edit the previous query like this:

```js
async function getUserTrainings() {
    const g = getTraversal();
    const result = await g.V()
        .hasLabel('user')
        .has('identityId', '1234')
        .as('u').outE()
        .hasLabel('trained')
        .inV()
        .path()
        .unfold()
        .where(P.neq('u'))
        .valueMap(true)
        .toList();
    closeConnection();
    console.log(result);
}
```

to get this output:

```
[ 
    Map {
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'id'
        } => { relationId: 'odxqw-3b4-27th-38o'
        },
    'title' => 'Political Science',
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'label'
        } => 'trained',
    'grade' => 'A'
    },
  Map {
    'name' => [ 'University of Illinois'
        ],
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'id'
        } => 4200,
    'identityId' => [ 'IL847'
        ],
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'label'
        } => 'institution'
    },
  Map {
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'id'
        } => { relationId: 'odxco-3b4-27th-3ao'
        },
    'title' => 'MS in Computer Science',
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'label'
        } => 'trained',
    'grade' => 'B'
    },
  Map {
    'name' => [ 'University of California'
        ],
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'id'
        } => 4272,
    'identityId' => [ 'CA83'
        ],
    EnumValue { typeName: 'T', elementName: 'label'
        } => 'institution'
    }
]
```

So, apart from the fact that the data returned it's not at all clear (I mean, what is that "typeName: 'T'" that's the same for every vertex?), now I do get back the properties, but I loose the outV and inV on the edges and I'm unable to reconstruct the data the way I need. (understand which vertex is connected by which edge).

I guess that I could just use the first query without the valueMap() step, and then for each and every vertex and edge I get back, will do another query to retrieve the properties using the ids.

And this could be ok for a simple situation like this, but I don't think it would be really efficient for queries that could concern hundreds of vertices and edges.

So the final question is: what is the most efficient way to reconstruct the data from a path, including vertices and edges properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just go to what I perceive as the heart of your question as I think the direct answer to that might clarify away the other sub-questions:

> let's say I want to retrieve all the trainings that a user took, and I'd also like to have the name of the institution where the training was taken

```
gremlin> g.V().has('user','identityId', '1234').
......1>   outE('trained').
......2>   project('institution','title','grade').
......3>     by(inV().values('name')).
......4>     by('title').
......5>     by('grade')
==>[institution:University of California,title:MS in Computer Science,grade:B]
==>[institution:University of Illinois,title:Political Science,grade:A]
```

One side question that I thought could use some clarification:

> what is that "typeName: 'T'" that's the same for every vertex?

`T` is an enum value in Gremlin and represents some core structural properties of graph elements, specifically `label` and `id`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Stephen. I actually just found out now, going through the gremlin library, that I can acces those EnumValues inside a Map importing t from gremlin.process.t. For what concerns the traversal, I guess being  new to gremlin is the main problem. Anyway, the traversal you suggested me is really neat, is there a way to also get the relationIds and vertexIds with something like it? Again thanks for your time

Comment: sure...just add more keys to `project()` and then for each one add a `by()` modulator to transform that "trained" edge into what you want that key to be. as you can see in the first `by()` you can pass an anonymous traversal as an argument so you have the full power of Gremlin to get whatever you want into that key.